# The CSS :checked ~ ul pseudoclass is not working

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, liveserver

I've read all the similar posts about this but none has worked for me so.

Im trying to make a responsive navigation bar with some YouTube tutorials, I have a checkbox to hide an show the menu when the width is to small. I've seen the console looking for bugs but there are no bugs, I've change the browser from chrome, to edge and to firefox but it doesn't seems to be the browser either. Also I changed the tags order in my HTML in order to accomplish the sibling general something rule but nothing has worked and Im kind of stuck whit this.

Here is my HTML code below:

```
<header>
        <nav>
            <img class="logo" src="/responsive1/logo.svg" alt="logo">
            <input type="checkbox" class="check">
            <label for="check" class="checkbtn">
                <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
            </label>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="active">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
```

And here is the CSS code which I want to use to hide and show the menu:

```
@media (max-width: 858px) {

ul {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #2c3e50;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .5s;
    }

.check:checked~ul{
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

**A relevant detail here is that when I add the ~ character and then I click the <input type="checkbox" ... in the browser inspector the @media it's not recognized but when I delete this character It is recognized.**

This is the tutorial I'm following, the exact part where he does it is in min 6:30:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oLgtucwjVII

Here is all the CSS code if it helps:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@500&display=swap');
* {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style: none;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: "Montserrat", sans-serif;
}

body header {
    background-color: #0082e6;
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
}

.logo {
    width: 150px;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 15px 100px;
    cursor: pointer;
}

nav ul {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

nav ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin: 0 5px;
}

nav ul li a {
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    padding: 7px 13px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

a .active,
a:hover {
    background-color: #1b9bff;
    transition: .5s;
}

.checkbtn {
    font-size: 30px;
    color: white;
    float: right;
    line-height: 80px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: none;
}

.check {
    display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 952px) {
    .logo {
        width: 100px;
        margin: 25px 50px;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 16px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 858px) {
    .checkbtn {
        display: block;
    }
    ul {
        position: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100vh;
        background: #2c3e50;
        top: 80px;
        left: -100%;
        text-align: center;
        transition: all .5s;
    }
    nav ul li {
        display: block;
        margin: 50px 0;
        line-height: 30px;
    }
    nav ul li a {
        font-size: 20px;
    }
    a:hover,
    a.active {
        background-color: none;
        color: #0082e6;
    }
    .check[type=checkbox]:checked~ul {
        left: 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: try with space ` ~ ` before and after tilde

Comment: @לבנימלכה I did it, but when I save it gets like joined, Im working with Visual Studio Code

Comment: Are you sure your viewport is less than 858px when you try to do this? You checkbox code is part of that media query.  here is your code with no changes: https://jsfiddle.net/whLo70ef/

Comment: @John yeah man I'm really sure, Idk why It works there, I've even tried in W3Schools editor and it didn't work there too

Comment: please open F12 in tab calls ELEMENT looks what happens to your css

Comment: Looking at your complete code, you have `display: none;` for the checkbox. so of course it wont work because there's no checkbox to check

Comment: Maybe consider using `opacity: 0;` if you want the checkbox to not appear but still be clickable.

Comment: @John I changed the display type before to show the checkbox It didn't worked, and I just try your last comment, it isn't working though

Comment: here's your code with the full CSS, and the only thing I changed was i removed `display: none;` from `.check` And it seems to be working. https://jsfiddle.net/whLo70ef/1/

Comment: @John I found the solution, I actually dont know thy It worked in JSFiddle but in case of visual studio code it was beacause It seems that the <label for="check" > tag just worked with and ID and I was working with a class. Thank u so much for helping me.

Comment: Glad you figured it out and happy to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

I was working with a class in the tag <input type="checkbox" **class="check"**> and the attribute <label **for="check"**> It seems to work just with ID's.